# Считывание данных для массива из консоли

Tags: php

Нужно считать числа из консоли, при этом, при вводе определённой цифры, нужно этот самый ввод прекращать. Ввод осуществляется таким образом: идут строки, в которых присутствуют числа или число, которые нужно записать в массив.

Вопрос, как это сделать?

Я пошёл следующим путём:

```
while($s = fgets($fh,1024)){
    if($s==0)
        break;
    else if(strlen($s)>1)
        $array += explode(' ', $s);
    else
        $array += explode('', $s);
}
```

Но, если я ввожу, допустим:

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
4 5 6\n
0
```

Получается массив `[1,5,6]`. Вопрос, что делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что делаю не так и как это исправить?

Неверно проводишь слияние массивов. Простое сложение добавит в результирующий массив ТОЛЬКО элементы с ключами, которых не было в первоначальном массиве.

```
php > $ar1 = [1,2,3];
php > $ar2 = [11,22,33,44];
php > $ar3 = $ar1 + $ar2;
php > echo implode(", ", $ar3);
1, 2, 3, 44
```

Используй `array_merge`:

```
$array = [];
foreach (["1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4 5 6\n", "0"] as $s) {
    $s = rtrim($s);
    if ($s == "0") {
        break;
    }
    $array = array_merge($array, array_map('intval', explode(' ', $s)));
}
var_export($array); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```